# OpenUI5 form validation on submit

Tags: sapui5

I'm starting with openui5. I want to validate all field of a form.

I'm using

```
sap.ui.getCore().getMessageManager().registerObject

this.getView().attachValidationError
```

on the controller and run perfect when I change the value of an input inside the form.

But what about to validate all form inputs when I trigger press event in the form button?

The only [solution](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputChecked/preview) I found, but this require to validate each field individually.

Is there not a way to invoke MessageManager to validate and render all fields?

Answer (score -1):

See this blog I wrote a while ago: http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/11/01/generic-sapui5-form-validator

It provides a means to validate your form at any given time, for instance when clicking a submit button

It is a bit too far-fetched to supply the utility class ([it's on GitHub](https://github.com/qualiture/ui5-validator)) but the idea behind it is the following:

- Identify your forms root container, and (recursively) find any children that inherit from `sap.ui.core.Control` (because you only want to validate controls of course)
- Check if the supplied control is something that can be visible and actually is visible (no sense in checking anything that cannot be visible)
- Then check if a constraint is set
- If yes, then try validating the control as if it were an inline validation
- However, if the control could not be validated, it may have aggregations that could be validated (i.e. it may be a form, a table, etc. which may hold child controls). We then check the children, and recursively call the validate method again

The main part is actually invoking every child control's validation:

```js
try {
    // get the control's binding (oControl is the control you want to validate)
    var oControlBinding = oControl.getBinding("value"); // or selectedKey, text, etc
    // get the formatted value
    var oExternalValue  = oControl.getProperty("value");
    // get the actual, internal value
    var oInternalValue  = oControlBinding.getType().parseValue(oExternalValue, oControlBinding.sInternalType);
    // trigger the actual validation
    oControlBinding.getType().validateValue(oInternalValue);
}
```

Comment: Is surprising for me that openui5 doesn't have a solution for this. Thanks for your answer.